# How to compress a HttpWebRequest POST

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, compression

I am trying to post data to server that accepts compressed data. The code below works just fine, but it is uncompressed.  I have not worked with compression or Gzip beofre, so any help is appriciated.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
  request.Timeout = 600000;
  request.Method = verb;  // POST    
  request.Accept = "text/xml";

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
  {
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";        

    byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;       

    // Here is where I need to compress the above byte array using GZipStream

    using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
      postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);         
    }
  }      

  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  HttpWebResponse response = null;
  StreamReader reader = null;
  try
  {
    response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
  }
```

Do I gzip the entire byte array?  Do I need to add other headers or remove the one that is already there?

Thanks!

-Scott

Answer (score 13):

To answer the question you asked, to POST compressed data, all you need to do is wrap the request stream with a gzip stream

```
 using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
    using(var zipStream = new GZipStream(postStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        zipStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);         
    }
 }
```

This is completely different than requesting a gzip response, which is a much more common thing to do.

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I am looking for.  However, I am getting a "can't close stream exc until all bytes are written" exception.  Still investigating that.  Flush() does not seem to help.  Also, I stil need to know what headers to use for this.

Comment: with @filipov [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23055905/492258) this become complete answer

Answer (score 5):

I also received the "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written" error using code similar to tnyfst's. The problem was that I had:

```
request.ContentLength = binData.Length;
```

where binData is my raw data before the compression. Obviously the length of the compressed content would be different, so I just removed this line and ended up with this code:

```
using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(request.GetRequestStream(), CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    zipStream.Write(binData, 0, binData.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also checked with fiddler and seems like content length is written automatically in this case

Answer (score 1):

In `Page_Load` event:

```
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

And for making compressed requests:

[HttpWebRequest and GZip Http Responses](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/102969.aspx) by *Rick Strahl*

Comment: The linked article explains how to decompress data returned in a response, but not how to structure the request using compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension method.
The stream will be left open (see the GZipStream constructor).
The stream position is set to 0 after the compression is done.

```
public static void GZip(this Stream stream, byte[] data)
{
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    stream.Position = 0;
}
```

You can use the following test:

```
[Test]
public void Test_gzip_data_is_restored_to_the_original_value()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var data = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    stream.GZip(data);

    var decompressed = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

    var data2 = new byte[10];
    decompressed.Read(data2,0,10);

    Assert.That(data, Is.EqualTo(data2));
}
```

For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158301(v=vs.110).aspx